# Adobe Air output log file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, output

I've built a Windows Air desktop application in Flash. When debugging in Flash there is an output panel with everything that's happening while the program is running. Does this panel exist when the Air app has been published, and is there a way to export the output to a text file so I can see if any errors are occurring?

I know this is a simple question, but I couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

1. You can grab some external Flash Tracer software like [Vizzy](https://github.com/capilkey/Vizzy-Flash-Tracer) and monitor the trace output like you've always been. When you're done debugging, don't forget to export a release build (it is smaller and faster than debug build).
2. You can devise your own output panel (a **TextField**, basically) and trace things there instead of **trace()** command.
3. You can grab some open source debug panel (there are actually plenty), e.g. my [Log](https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/022a2f6fcb1c6752a76575df95b117fbca861328/classes/ru/delimiter/utils/Log.as?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Usage:

```
// At the root constructor.
// Create a Log panel and show it.
Log.create(this, true);

// App start output.
Log.log("Hello World!", "This is SPARTA!!!");

// Handle uncaught exceptions.
Log.handleExceptions(this, true);

// Lets test how exceptions work.
(null)(null);
```

So instead of **trace(...)** you just put **Log.log(...)** everywhere, and that's it. **Log** also traces everything, so you won't notice the difference. To show/hide Log panel press **F3** or other bunch of keys reserved in the code (you are free to modify these or add your own show/hide keys):

```
static private const PASS:String = "/*@&^#";
```